# ros_android load plugins for move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

concerning this tutorial: [android_ndk_pluginlib](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/UsingPluginlib)

i set up my android robot with ros_android and everything is working so far including amcl.
But i cant get the plugins to work. The plugins i need are base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS costmap2d/inflationlayer
obstacle layer and  static_layer.
Usually i would load them by setting the according Parameters in the XML and YAML files like this:

```
- {name: static_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer'}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: 'costmap_2d::InflationLayer'}
```

but with ros_android i dont have that option.
To set the parameters i use:

```
        ParameterTree params = connectedNode.getParameterTree();
        params.set("move_base_node/global_costmap/plugins/name/inflation_layer", "costmap_2d/StaticLayer");
```

which doesn't seem to work.

In the android.mk file i have included

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcostmap_2d libbase_local_planner libglobal_planner
```

any help would be very welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300148/ros_android-load-plugins-for-move_base/) by [manster2209](https://answers.ros.org/users/35175/manster2209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @manster2209,

I think I've answered that question in [this post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-android-ndk/278/3?u=jubeira) in ROS discourse. Please check out that answer; an example for the cross compiled navigation stack for Android is provided there.

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manster2209](https://answers.ros.org/users/35175/manster2209/) on 2018-08-15**:
Yes you did!
Thank you very much!
I am currently looking into that solution! It looks very promising. You are doing great work!
Can I reach out to you if I have any more Questions?
Kind regards!

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-08-15**:
Sure! Feel free to do so, or to open a new thread here in ROS answers (it may also help others that are facing the same problems). I regularly check for new questions if they are tagged with `rosjava`, `android` and / or related tags; I will respond as soon as possible.